# How to read a CSV from an HTTP Request using Django

Tags: python-2.7, django-1.8

I am trying to use an HTTP Request to accept a CSV and then I am trying to get the data from each column in the CSV into a list. The problem is that whenever I try to get the data from the CSV it constantly returns as a blank list on my command line.

I have tried using IO:

```
csv_file = request.DATA
csv = csv_file.content.decode('utf-8')        
data_set = csv.reader(io.StringIO(csv))
print data_set
```

However this results in an Attribute Error.

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'content'
  File "C:\Users\Varun\Documents\BitBucket\api\apicall\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Varun\Documents\BitBucket\api\apicall\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Varun\Documents\BitBucket\api\apicall\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Varun\Documents\BitBucket\api\apicall\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 407, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Varun\Documents\BitBucket\api\apicall\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 404, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Varun\Documents\BitBucket\api\remodel\views.py", line 4922, in put
    csv = csv_file.content.decode('utf-8')
```

```
class LeadCSVInvite(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    parser_class = (FileUploadParser, MultiPartParser)

    def put(self, request, filename, format=None):      
        csv_file = request.DATA
        csv = csv_file.content.decode('utf-8')
        print csv
## Check the messages.error
        # if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
        #     return Response(status=400)
        #     #return Response({'errorCode': 1, 'errorMsg': "not csv"}, content_type= 'application/json',  status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        data_set = csv.reader(io.StringIO(csv))
        print data_set
        # print data_set
        # io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
        # next(io_string)
        emails = []
        names = []
        for column in data_set:
            print column
            first_name = column[0],
            email = column[1]
            emails.append(email)
            names.append(first_name)
        for i in range(len(emails)):
            if emails[i] is None:
                return Response(status=400)
                #return Response({'errorCode': 1, 'errorMsg': "no email"}, content_type= 'application/json',  status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            print emails[i]
            emails[i] = emails[i].lower().strip()
            client_exists = User.objects.filter(email=emails[i]).exists()

            if names[i] is None and not client_exists:
                return Response(status=400)
                #return Response({'errorCode': 2, 'errorMsg': "no first name"}, content_type = 'application/json', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            elif names[i] is not None:
                client_name = names[i].strip()
            print names[i]
```

I expect the names and emails list to be populated with the data from the first and second column of the CSV respectively.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body

Answer (score 0):

The error itself shows that you are trying to call content attribute against a dict. Findout how csv file is passed from the frontend.